# UI Activity Refresh

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I refresh an activity when User is currently viewing that activity only.
 I need to show modified listview items which are modified in server. 
I am already getting updated dataitems but dun know how to refresh the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` every time the data change in your adapter so this will 
Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Comment: what if i'm on some other activity... Like if i'm on current activity then it should be refreshed and if i'm on some other activity then it'd be changed to required activity.. Hows that possible..

Answer (score 0):

As you've already updated data, just the following code

```
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```